# Autocomplete input covered regular form input. How to submit form with autocomplete input

Tags: html, angular, input, autocomplete, angular-material

I want to search with a autocomplete input, but autocomplete result doesn't bind on form input search button. It looks like input text is pristine although I gave some autocomplete result (search button is still disabled).

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <section class="form-block">

    <div class="form-group" id="customerIdFormGroup">
      <label class="required" for="customerIdInput">Customer ID</label>

      <input type="text"
             id="customerIdInput"
             (keyup.enter)="emitSearch()"
             formControlName="customerId"

             matInput
             [formControl]="myControl"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto">

             <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
                {{ option }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
    <button type="button"
            id="searchButton"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            [disabled]="searchForm.pristine"
            (click)="emitSearch()">
      Search
    </button>
    <button type="reset"
            id="clearButtonInvoice"
            class="btn btn-link text-primary"
            (click)="emitClear()">
      Clear
    </button>
  </section>
</form>
```

I used angular materiel 7.3.1 with  .
If I remove  `matInput` part, the search button works well,

```
[formControl]="myControl"
[matAutocomplete]="auto"
```

but without autocomplete feature.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <section class="form-block">

    <div class="form-group" id="customerIdFormGroup">
      <label class="required" for="customerIdInput">Customer ID</label>

      <input type="text"
         id="customerIdInput"
         (keyup.enter)="emitSearch()"
         formControlName="customerId"

         matInput
         [formControl]="myControl"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">

         <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
    <button type="button"
        id="searchButton"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        [disabled]="searchForm.pristine"
        (click)="emitSearch()">
  Search
    </button>
    <button type="reset"
        id="clearButtonInvoice"
        class="btn btn-link text-primary"
        (click)="emitClear()">
  Clear
    </button>
  </section>
</form>
```

I expect I can search with autocomplete input. After some input text is given, the search button suppose to be activate and I can search with the text.

Comment: export class SearchByCustomerIdComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['N3RSRCORP', 'N0KINGKULL', 'N3CACTUS', 'N3RCACORP', 'N4UPS' , 'N4UPSAMER' , 'N4UNISTAR' , 'N4UPS', 'N4UPSTRUCk'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  @Input() searchForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() searchByCustomerId: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() clear: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  emitSearch() {
    this.searchByCustomerId.emit();
  }

Answer (score 0):

The input pristine status is not changing because you have two formControl directive on your input, remove [formControl]="myControl" from input element.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group" id="customerIdFormGroup">
      <label class="required" for="customerIdInput">Customer ID</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="customerIdInput"
             (keyup.enter)="emitSearch()"
             formControlName="customerId"
             matInput
             [matAutocomplete]="auto">

             <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
                {{ option }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
    <button type="button"
            id="searchButton"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            [disabled]="searchForm.pristine"
            (click)="emitSearch()">
      Search
    </button>
    <button type="reset"
            id="clearButtonInvoice"
            class="btn btn-link text-primary"
            (click)="emitClear()">
      Clear
    </button>
  </section>
</form>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tzq4w)

Comment: [formControl] contains autocomplete logic and content in ts file. If I remove it, there won't be autocomplete feature.

Comment: That formControlName comes from regular HTML form input, bind to event emitter with search button. [formControl] comes from angular/material, it takes autocomplete feature. I am not sure if I can combine them.

Comment: As far i know both are samd except formControlName wil be used inside formGroup, FormControl can be used directly without formGroup

Comment: Problem solved. We do need only one formControl, then change API path in ts file. Thank you for your help :)